# Set Cassandra Clustering Order on TableDef with Datastax's Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

**Every time I try to create a new table in cassandra with a new `TableDef` I end up with a clustering order of ascending and I'm trying to get descending.**

I'm using Cassandra 2.1.10, Spark 1.5.1, and Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector 1.5.0-M2.

I'm creating a new `TableDef`

```
val table = TableDef("so", "example", 
  Seq(ColumnDef("parkey", PartitionKeyColumn, TextType)),
  Seq(ColumnDef("ts", ClusteringColumn(0), TimestampType)),
  Seq(ColumnDef("name", RegularColumn, TextType)))

rdd.saveAsCassandraTableEx(table, SomeColumns("key", "time", "name"))
```

What I'm expecting to see in Cassandra is

```
CREATE TABLE so.example (
    parkey text,
    ts timestamp,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((parkey), ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

What I end up with is

```
CREATE TABLE so.example (
    parkey text,
    ts timestamp,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((parkey), ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC);
```

How can I force it to set the clustering order to descending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find a direct way of doing this. Additionally there are a lot of other options you may want to specify. I ended up extending `ColumnDef` and `TableDef` and overriding the `cql` method in `TableDef`. An example of the solution I came up with is below. If someone has a better way or this becomes natively supported I'd be happy to change the answer.

```
// Scala Enum
object ClusteringOrder {
  abstract sealed class Order(val ordinal: Int) extends Ordered[Order]
    with Serializable {
    def compare(that: Order) = that.ordinal compare this.ordinal

    def toInt: Int = this.ordinal
  }

  case object Ascending extends Order(0)
  case object Descending extends Order(1)

  def fromInt(i: Int): Order = values.find(_.ordinal == i).get

  val values = Set(Ascending, Descending)
}

// extend the ColumnDef case class to add enum support
class ColumnDefEx(columnName: String, columnRole: ColumnRole, columnType: ColumnType[_],
  indexed: Boolean = false, val clusteringOrder: ClusteringOrder.Order = ClusteringOrder.Ascending)
  extends ColumnDef(columnName, columnRole, columnType, indexed)

// Mimic the ColumnDef object
object ColumnDefEx {
  def apply(columnName: String, columnRole: ColumnRole, columnType: ColumnType[_],
    indexed: Boolean, clusteringOrder: ClusteringOrder.Order): ColumnDef = {
    new ColumnDefEx(columnName, columnRole, columnType, indexed, clusteringOrder)
  }

  def apply(columnName: String, columnRole: ColumnRole, columnType: ColumnType[_],
    clusteringOrder: ClusteringOrder.Order = ClusteringOrder.Ascending): ColumnDef = {
    new ColumnDefEx(columnName, columnRole, columnType, false, clusteringOrder)
  }

  // copied from ColumnDef object
  def apply(column: ColumnMetadata, columnRole: ColumnRole): ColumnDef = {
    val columnType = ColumnType.fromDriverType(column.getType)
    new ColumnDefEx(column.getName, columnRole, columnType, column.getIndex != null)
  }
}

// extend the TableDef case class to override the cql method
class TableDefEx(keyspaceName: String, tableName: String, partitionKey: Seq[ColumnDef],
  clusteringColumns: Seq[ColumnDef], regularColumns: Seq[ColumnDef], options: String)
  extends TableDef(keyspaceName, tableName, partitionKey, clusteringColumns, regularColumns) {

  override def cql = {
    val stmt = super.cql
    val ordered = if (clusteringColumns.size > 0)
      s"$stmt\r\nWITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (${clusteringColumnOrder(clusteringColumns)})"
    else stmt
    appendOptions(ordered, options)
  }

  private[this] def clusteringColumnOrder(clusteringColumns: Seq[ColumnDef]): String =
    clusteringColumns.map { col =>
      col match {
        case c: ColumnDefEx => if (c.clusteringOrder == ClusteringOrder.Descending)
          s"${c.columnName} DESC" else s"${c.columnName} ASC"
        case c: ColumnDef => s"${c.columnName} ASC"
      }
    }.toList.mkString(", ")

  private[this] def appendOptions(stmt: String, opts: String) =
    if (stmt.contains("WITH") && opts.startsWith("WITH")) s"$stmt\r\nAND ${opts.substring(4)}"
    else if (!stmt.contains("WITH") && opts.startsWith("AND")) s"WITH ${opts.substring(3)}"
    else s"$stmt\r\n$opts"
}

// Mimic the TableDef object but return new TableDefEx
object TableDefEx {
  def apply(keyspaceName: String, tableName: String, partitionKey: Seq[ColumnDef],
    clusteringColumns: Seq[ColumnDef], regularColumns: Seq[ColumnDef], options: String = "") =
    new TableDefEx(keyspaceName, tableName, partitionKey, clusteringColumns, regularColumns,
      options)

  def fromType[T: ColumnMapper](keyspaceName: String, tableName: String): TableDef =
    implicitly[ColumnMapper[T]].newTable(keyspaceName, tableName)
}
```

This allowed me to create new tables in this manner:

```
val table = TableDefEx("so", "example", 
  Seq(ColumnDef("parkey", PartitionKeyColumn, TextType)),
  Seq(ColumnDefEx("ts", ClusteringColumn(0), TimestampType, ClusteringOrder.Descending)),
  Seq(ColumnDef("name", RegularColumn, TextType)))

rdd.saveAsCassandraTableEx(table, SomeColumns("key", "time", "name"))
```